# Navigating to a directory in Mac with Finder

Tags: mac

In the picture below I have download a file ( that Maven folder ) and following the installation instructions it is asking to

> If you expanded the archive into the directory
>   /usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.3, you may want to create a symbolic link
>   to make it easier to work with and to avoid the need to change any
>   environment configuration when you upgrade to a newer version:

So my first question actually how to navigate to the folder that is listed above in their instructions?
 ( quoted from here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/installation-sect-maven-install.html )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

Open Terminal and type:

```
open /usr/local/
```

Or from Finder, on the menu bar click **Go** -> **Go to folder…**. Then type `/usr/local` and click **OK**.

Answer (score 2):

You can also press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> in Finder and in its dialogs. The big advantage here: You can still use tab-completion. If you type `/u` followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will expand to `/usr/`.

Answer (score 0):

And a third option is to show hidden files in a finder. You can change it using terminal. In terminal, paste the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
```

Press return.

Then relaunch finder using following command:

```
killall Finder
```

That's all. When you want to change back, make it again with changed value YES to NO